# How to add ErrorDescription to Zend Sub Form Element?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have the following code that makes a sub form from a table, I have the error description saved in the database, I know how to set it for normal elements but not when it is a subform, how can I add a custom error message per subform element?

```
    $subForm = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
    foreach($configuration as $config){

        $elements[] = array(
            new Zend_Form_Element_Text($config->configuration_key, array(
                'required'   => (($config->is_required == 1) ? true : false),
                'label'      => $config->configuration_title,
                'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
                'value'     => $config->configuration_value,
                'Options'   => array('style'=>'width:90%;'),
                'Description' => $config->configuration_description,
                'errorMessage' => $config->errorMessage,

            ))
        );


    }
    $subForm->addElements($elements);
    $this->addSubForm($subForm, 'configuration');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing a lot with the different options and trial/error I found out that I needed to add 'ErrorMessages' as an array, I rewrote my snippet

```
        $elementSettings = array(
                'required'   => (($config->is_required == 1) ? true : false),
                'label'      => $config->configuration_title,
                'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
                'value'     => $config->configuration_value,
                'Options'   => array('style'=>'width:90%;'),
                'Description' => $config->configuration_description,
                'ErrorMessages' => array($config->errorMessage)
            );
         $elements[] = array(new Zend_Form_Element_Text($config->configuration_key, $elementSettings));
```